# Download content of several files on server with PHP

Tags: php

I have 2 files - *1.csv* and *2.csv*. I can download *1.csv* with PHP by known approach:

```
$file = '1.csv';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

But my purpose is to have in downloaded file content of both files - *1.csv* and *2.csv*. Does anybody have some ideas how to implement this? 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Define "the content of both files". Do you want to concatenate the files into one longer file? Or do you want the user to get two different files?

Comment: read both files in one string maybe and output as 1-2.csv ?

Comment: That's right - to concatenate the files into one longer file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly this should do it.

```
$file1 = '1.csv';
$file2 = '2.csv';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/comma-separated-values');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file1, '.csv') . '-'  . basename($file2, '.csv') . '.csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($file1) + filesize($file2)));
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file1);
readfile($file2);
```

Consider using a loop for multiple files and mind the change of the Content-Type header for CSV files.

Comment: This does not work..it only downloads the first file. Did you test this?

Comment: Yep, I did. Did you use the content length calculation from my example?

Depending on the content of the first file you probably have to put an additional newline between the readfiles (this would also need you to add the size of the newline to the Content-Length header). When it still shows the content of the first file only, maybe your second one is empty?

Comment: That s odd..It prompts me to download one file and contains only data of the first one

Comment: Actually my code should do the same as yours, except for the filename header magic. Also `readfile()` should be more efficient for bigger files as it writes directly into the output buffer.

Comment: Cool. Upvote or accept would also be fine for me (and surely for radashk too) ...

Comment: Of course I tried to accept your answers. But in reply it was written to me that "Vote Up requires 15 reputation":(

Answer (score 1):

```
$file1 = '1.csv';
$file2 = '2.csv';
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/jpeg');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="1-2.csv"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . (filesize($file1)+filesize($file2)));
ob_clean();
flush();
echo file_get_contents($file1).file_get_contents($file2);
```

Downloads the concatenation of the 2 file contents